# self-heating effect of dual PT100 temperature probe in a moving mass of water

Tags: analog, heat, rtd, pt100

I'm trying to know how much self-heating should I expect in these conditions:

- Temperature range: 0-45 C
- Using a 1050Ohm pullup resistor to feed each PT100 (2-wire configuration) with 5 volt excitation and 5 volt reference.
- Temperature probe with two PT100 inside
- Temperature probe will be inserted in a pipe with a moving mass of water using a thermowhell.

According with what I've read in several sites, including this [texas instruments reference](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidude4/tidude4.pdf) the self-heating coefficient should be 0.01-0.02 C/mW for a moving mass of water.

with a 5V excitation, 1050 Ohm resistor and max value of 117.47Ohm of the PT100 at 45C I get 2.1546mW so the temperature would raise the negligible amount of 0.043 mK using 0.02 C/mW coefficient. Am I right in my calculations? Also, since both PT100 are fitted in the same probe, may they affect each other in terms of heat in a significant way?

EDIT: Andy  corrected my calculation error and introduced the water SH as a variable but Spehro answered my second cuestion and provided more practical info./tips :

- Increased thermal resistance from poor thermowell coupling.
- Self heating coefficient being variable depending on material,construction.

Comment: you can further reduce self-heating by grounding the pull-up between measurements

Comment: @Jasen that's a good idea but I have to fit the circuit in the probe's head and I don't have space left in the PCB to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be better off to get actual self-heating numbers from the probe manufacturer (or make measurements yourself). The coefficient can vary over a range of 10:1 depending on RTD element and probe construction (thin film vs. wound and epoxy vs. alumina packing, for example). The probe material will affect it too. TI is a semiconductor maker, not an expert in probe design. If you have a separate probe assembly loose inside a thermowell, it will be worse again! At least you have flowing water which is the next best thing to flowing molten metal.

I would consider 5mA to be an excessive current for a Pt100, usually we use 1mA, so you are getting 25x as much self heating. That's a pretty heavy price to pay for a less professional design of signal conditioner if you care about accuracy.

Most certainly the two elements will interact, again it will depend on the exact construction.

Comment: Thanks Spehro, could you explain why using a thermowell would make it worse again? also, are you saying that flowing water not only doesn't provide better self-heating coefficient but also makes it worse?

Comment: The thermowell provides more thermal resistance so a given amount of power dissipation results in more offset. If it's not spring loaded the coupling can be quite poor. No, I am saying flowing water is about as good as it gets.

Comment: great info but regarding the PT100 current I can't go for 1mA because I need very high resolution 0.001C out of a 10-25mV signal so I need to meet a compromise between the Pull-up resistor, ADC-Vref/Excitation voltage and S/N ratio but I'm leaving that for another post

Answer (score 1):

It's always worth double-checking that water's specific heat (SH) doesn't vary too much with temperature: -

[image]

[Picture source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287910/why-water-heat-capacity-has-minimum-at-body-temperature).

As can be seen, the SH doesn't vary much over the range of temperatures you are considering so it's reasonable to conclude that water temperaure doesn't significantly alter its thermal conductivity in this range.

With the PT100 at 45 degC, its resistance is 117.5 ohms and hence it will develop across it a voltage of 0.503 volts and dissipate a power of 2.16 mW.

Using the TI figure of thermal resistance of 0.02 degC/mW the self heating temperature rise will be less than 0.05 degrees.

Comment: Right, I miscalculated when applying the self-heating coefficient and ended up with 0.05 mK when It's actually 0.05 K. Should I be able to correct this with a multipoint calibration?

Answer (score 0):

### General case

You have a voltage divider made of a unknown resistor and a 1.05 kΩ resistor, driven from 5 V.  The highest dissipation in the unknown resistor happens when its resistance matches the fixed resistance.  Therefore, you want to know the dissipation of a 1.05 kΩ resistor is with 2.5 V across it.

(2.5 V)<sup>2</sup>/(1.05 kΩ) = 6 mW

At 0.02 °C/mW self-heating, that comes out to 0.12 °C.

### Your specific case

You now say the maximum resistance of the thermistor is 117.5 Ω.  That means the maximum dissipation will also be lower.  With the other resistor of the voltage divider being 1.05 kΩ, the voltage across the 117.5 Ω resistor is 503 mV.

(503 mV)<sup>2</sup>/(117.5 Ω) = 2.2 mW

That times the 0.02 °C/mW yields 0.043 °C.

Comment: PT100 value is 100-117.47Ohm in the 0-45C range, I'm adding that info in the original post

Comment: Sorry, Olin, you missed the mark. "resistance matches the fixed resistance" will never happen. This is a platinum RTD, not a thermistor.

Comment: @What: A platinum RTD *is* a thermistor.  Also, I was making no assumptions about the thermistor itself, going to the basic physics of the maximum possible dissipation of a resistor of a voltage divider.  Now that the OP has specified the maximum value of the thermistor, I'll update the answer.